# Delphi Marshalling my object to string leaks, but why?

Tags: delphi, marshalling, datasnap

I wonder why the marshalling of my object to a string leaks, I've tried to free up the JSONMarshal (and in fact also tried to free the converter, by instantiating it) - but it still leaks? Shouldn't it be enough to free the JSONMarshal?

```
function TPerson.ToJsonString: string;
var
  JSONMarshal: TJSONMarshal;
begin
  result := '';
  JSONMarshal := TJSONMarshal.Create(TJSONConverter.Create);
  try
    Result := JSONMarshal.Marshal(self).ToString;
  finally
    JSONMarshal.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Here's a test object - just make an instance of TPerson (1, ') and call the ToJsonString - then you'll see the leak.

```
unit TestObjU;

interface

uses
  Classes, System.Generics.Collections, System.SysUtils,
  Data.DBXJSON, Data.DBXJSONReflect, JSON,
  Data.FireDACJSONReflect, FireDAC.Comp.Client, vcl.ExtCtrls,
  pngimage, graphics, variants;

type
  EPerson = class(Exception);
  EPersonsList = class(Exception);

  TGender = (Female, Male);

  TPerson = class(TObject)
  private
    FFirstName: string;
    FLastName: string;
    FId: Integer;
    FGender: TGender;
    FModified : Boolean;
    [JSONMarshalled(False)]
    FPicture : TPicture;
    function GetName: string;
    procedure SetFirstName(const Value: string);
    procedure SetLastName(const Value: string);
    function GetId: Integer;
    procedure SetGender(const Value: TGender);
    procedure SetModified(const Value: Boolean);


  public
    property Id : Integer read GetId;
    property Name : string read GetName;
    property FirstName : string read FFirstName write SetFirstName;
    property LastName : string read FLastName write SetLastName;
    property Gender : TGender read FGender write SetGender;
    property Modified : Boolean read FModified write SetModified;
    [JSONMarshalled(False)]
    property Picture : TPicture read FPicture write FPicture;
    function Update : Boolean;
    function Delete : Boolean;

    constructor Create(AId : Integer; AFirstName, ALastName : string; AGender : TGender); overload;
    destructor destroy; override;

    function ToJsonString: string;
    class function FromJsonString(AJSONString: string): TPerson; static;

  end;

implementation

{ TPerson }

constructor TPerson.Create(AId: Integer; AFirstName, ALastName: string;
  AGender: TGender);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FPicture := TPicture.Create;
  FId := AId;
  FFirstName := AFirstName;
  FLastName := ALastName;
  FGender := AGender;
end;

function TPerson.Delete: Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  if (FId > 0) then // if Id below zero we have a problem
  begin
    Result := True;
    FModified := False;
  end;
end;

destructor TPerson.destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FPicture);
  inherited;
end;

function TPerson.GetId: Integer;
begin
  Result := FId;
end;

function TPerson.GetName: string;
begin
  Result := FFirstName + ' ' + FLastName;
end;

procedure TPerson.SetFirstName(const Value: string);
begin
  FFirstName := Value;
  FModified := True;
end;

procedure TPerson.SetGender(const Value: TGender);
begin
  FGender := Value;
  FModified := True;
end;

procedure TPerson.SetLastName(const Value: string);
begin
  FLastName := Value;
  FModified := True;
end;

procedure TPerson.SetModified(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  FModified := Value;
end;

function TPerson.ToJsonString: string;
var
  JSONMarshal: TJSONMarshal;
begin
  result := '';
  JSONMarshal := TJSONMarshal.Create(TJSONConverter.Create, True);
  try
    Result := JSONMarshal.Marshal(self).ToString;
  finally
    JSONMarshal.Free;
  end;
end;

class function TPerson.FromJsonString(AJSONString: string): TPerson;
var
  JSONUnMarshal: TJSONUnMarshal;
begin
  JSONUnMarshal := TJSONUnMarshal.Create;
  try
    Result := JSONUnMarshal.Unmarshal(TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(AJSONString)) as TPerson;
  finally
    JSONUnMarshal.Free;
  end;
end;

function TPerson.Update: Boolean;
var
  AStream : TMemoryStream;
begin
  if (FId > 0) then // if Id below zero we have a problem
  begin
    AStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(AStream);
      AStream.Position := 0; // wind back if needed
    finally
      FreeAndNil(AStream);
    end;
  end;
  FModified := False;
end;

{ TPersonsList<T> }


end.



procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  APerson : TPerson;
begin

  APerson := TPerson.Create(1, 'Donald', 'Duck', Male);
  try

    Memo1.Lines.Add(APerson.ToJsonString);

  finally
    APerson.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: How you have detected the leak? Using FastMM?

Comment: An [mcve] would be useful. Can't we have one. Perhaps this is relevant: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=81862 and I think we should know the delphi version too

Comment: I have only used 
ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;

I'll see if I can get a FastMM log and I'm using XE10 upd1

Comment: That report is a very long file 3000+ lines - should I insert it here?

Comment: Key stack traces are what matter most. Post them.

Comment: Your referenced case look very similar indeed.... and it's from 2010....
qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=81862

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marshal returns a `TJSONValue` instance and it seems to me that you need to destroy this instance.

```
function TPerson.ToJsonString: string;
var
  JSONMarshal: TJSONMarshal;
  Value: TJSONValue;
begin
  JSONMarshal := TJSONMarshal.Create(TJSONConverter.Create, True);
  try
    Value := JSONMarshal.Marshal(Self);
    try
      Result := Value.ToString;
    finally
      Value.Free;
    end;
  finally
    JSONMarshal.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Your method that operates in the opposite direction makes the same mistake. It should be:

```
class function TPerson.FromJsonString(AJSONString: string): TPerson;
var
  JSONUnMarshal: TJSONUnMarshal;
  Value: TJSONValue;
begin
  JSONUnMarshal := TJSONUnMarshal.Create;
  try
    Value := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(AJSONString);
    try
      Result := JSONUnMarshal.Unmarshal(Value) as TPerson;
    finally
      Value.Free;
    end;
  finally
    JSONUnMarshal.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Yes you are right, the JSONvalue must be freed - that solves the leak.
Thanks